# Cloud Storage with API that support file detection

Tags: c#, dropbox, google-drive-api, onedrive, cloud-storage

Hi I am looking for some cloud storage (Dropbox, SkyDrive, Google Drive, etc) that has a decent API (C#) and has some sort of subscription service, so that when a new file is added it will inform me of it, so I can pick it up and work with it. Does this even exist or will I have to poll the cloud storage every x minutes.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Drive this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303297/can-my-app-be-notified-of-file-updates-on-my-google-drive-folder/10303455#10303455) already.

Basically this is not available yet on the Drive API but we have got it planned for a future release. In the mean time you should check out the [changes feed of the Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#detecting_changes_to_resources) that is very convenient for polling.